# Theos error with mavericks and iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos

I set up theos and work on jailbreak tweaks.. i read on the web that rpetrich's headers were only compatible with his theos fork.
So i cloned his theos fork from github and dumped his headers to the `/include` folder..

then i had to add ldid and libsubstrate.dylib to the theos folder, which i did following instructions from [iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started#For_Mac_OS_X)

then i followed [this](http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-your-first-tweak) tutorial to make a simple tweak

**INFO:** I'm trying to run this on mavericks using an iOS7 SDK

**The problem:** 
i followed the tutorial perfectly! but for some reason i get this error:

```
Sahils-MacBook-Pro:welcomewagon Sahil$ make
/Users/Sahil/Documents/tweaks/welcomewagon/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:48:               Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak WelcomeWagon...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `internal-library-compile'.
```

What does this even mean > `Nothing to be done for 'internal-library-compile'.`

My code is:

**Tweak.xm** :

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
%orig;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" 
    message:@"Welcome to your iPhone Brandon!" 
    delegate:nil 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}

%end
```

**Makefile:**

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

ARCHS = armv7

TWEAK_NAME = WelcomeWagon
WelcomeWagon_FILES = Tweak.xm
WelcomeWagon_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit


include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nothing to be done for 'internal-library-compile'.` is not an error. It means that there is nothing to be done for the library compile step.

This is GNU make's way of telling you that *your tweak is already compiled, and nothing has changed since you last compiled it.* There is "nothing to be done" to it.